# At which point does the .NET Process.Start method return to the calling method?

Tags: c#, .net

When running [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) in a .NET application we wait until the process has started or failed rather than continuing in the calling program/method - is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a read at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx. Process.Start will return once the process is launched. If you want to wait until the process has exited, then you need to call WaitForExit.

Be aware that there are potential deadlock issues if you are redirecting StandardOutput and StandardError and calling WaitForExit. If you are not reading the streams for StandardOutput and StandardError then the buffer can fill and the process will block. Hence WaitForExit will never return. The usual solution is to put calls to ReadToEnd on the StandardOutput and StandardError in threadpool threads and call WaitForExit on the main thread.

Comment: Is it safe to call Process.GetProcessById(PID) after a call to Process.Start() ? I mean, am I guaranteed that GetProcessById will return the correct result all the time? Of course, assuming that the started process does not immediately close after start

Comment: Apologies, I only saw this comment now. 1 year late is still useful, right? Anyway, GetProcessById after Process.Start should be fine, but you now have a race condition and you rely on the process not having finished before you call GetProcessById. It may complete without failure before you call GetProcessById. But more importantly, if you're starting the process with Process.Start, it returns the Process object to you - you don't need to get it from GetProcessById. In this case, you can still interrogate the Process object after it has completed (eg for exit code).

Answer (score 0):

Once the the application launched by Process.Start has began (or failed to launch) then control returns to your application.